# Question on Mathematical Logic & Book Recommendation

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

*I'm in the last year of my undergraduate studies in mathematics and I would appreciate your oppinion in the following thought.*

Should I study Mathematical Logic, if I want to do further studies in Algebra and/or applied Algebra? Will this be useful?

And if the answer is yes, could you please recommend me a good book for Mathematical Logic, which containing the following?

- **Propositional Calculus:** The Language of Propositional Calculus. Truth Values, appreciation, logical implications. Axiomatization of propositional calculus, completeness. Independence of axioms.
- **Predicate Calculus:** 1st order languages. Structures, Models, Truth. Axiomatization of 1st order Predicate Calculus, completeness.

And at last, do you have further advises for how to study this course?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Those topics are covered well by textbooks by Mendelson and by Enderton, both of which are well regarded.

Comment: I think Mendelson's book is a little bit difficult. And spesifically I find the exersices difficult. But, Enderton is good I think.

Answer (score 1):

For the topics you've listed, *Logic and Structure* by van Dalen is a good, math-oriented book that you should be able to work through by yourself.

Doing some logic will help you better understand what proofs are, which is good if you're a mathematician! But you should not really expect it to help you directly solve research problems (in algebra, or other branches of pure math) except for *very specific* occasional problems that turn out to have slick logic-based proofs, that logicians will be happy to brag about if you ask them to. :) However, the "logic" that's used is inevitably harder than what you'll get from a first pass at propositional and predicate logic. For that, you should work through something like van Dalen first, then if your research interests require it, learn more model theory/proof theory/descriptive set theory/whatever at some later point.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your advises. I already got van Dalen's book, and looks very good. So, you think that logic useful directly in Algebra, but in some spesifuc occasions will be.

Comment: Sure, but the most important thing for algebra is... to learn lots of algebra! Work through a good abstract algebra book like Artin or Dummit and Foote. And, if you think that "category theory" is a branch of logic (this is debatable), it is by far the most useful as an algebraist, so set aside some time to learn the basic pieces of category theory - universal mapping properties, duality arguments, directed limits, functors and natural transformations, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful advices. Do you thing that logic is useful for category theory?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested at learning mathematical logic, I strongly recommend that you check out Richard Hodel's *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic*. It covers everything you mention (some in the form of lengthy exercises with hints), the exposition is admirably clear, and, most importantly, it's cheap, since it has been re-published by Dover! I've found it *immensely* useful and it's one of my favorite logic books.

As for whether mathematical logic will help you with algebra, I'd say that there is a nice interplay here between algebraic and logical ideas. On the one hand, algebraic ideas in many cases serve either as inspiration or proto-types for properly logical ideas (for instance, I was always struck by the analogies between the construction of the splitting field for a polynomial and Henkin's term models), and, on the other hand, getting the hang of logic may help you to get a deeper understanding of the underlying algebra (here, I found Robinson's ideas of model completeness, especially as developed by [Manders](https://www.pdcnet.org//pdc/bvdb.nsf/purchase?openform&fp=jphil&id=jphil_1989_0086_0010_0553_0562&onlyautologin=true), to be very enlightening). Of course, this rarely will lead you to a new result, but the resulting clarity may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, Hodel's book isn't available in my department's library and I couldn't find something on internet... So, I don't know what to do. 

And, as far as this course, your opinion is to attend it. Right?

Comment: @Chris - I do recommend that you at least take a look at it (you can see some sample pages on Amazon) and, if it interests you, as I said, it's relatively cheap. And yes, I think taking a course on logic, especially if you later study model theory, can be useful.

Comment: What do you believe about the book "Mathematical Logic by Rene Cori, Daniel Lascar, Donald Pelletier"? Do you think that its a well-written book and contains all the topics above?

Comment: @Chris It's been a while since I last checked that book. I remember that the exposition was a bit terse, so that I ended up using it just for the exercises.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your advice, and I 'll check it only for exercises.

Comment: @Chris - It has come to my attention that Chris Leary and Lars Kristiansen's excellent *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic* is now available for free here: https://minerva.geneseo.edu/a-friendly-introduction-to-mathematical-logic/